Gamma trading PnL
I understand this delta hedged portfolio pnl formula and how it's derived.
$$
\text{P&L}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma(\Delta S)^{2}-\theta\delta t 
$$
However, if I think it from a different angle like this:  say if $\Gamma$ is known and stock dollar move is $\Delta S$, and then how much my delta would move is $\frac{\Delta S}{S}*\Gamma$. Can I argue that my dollar $\text{P&L}$ is just $\frac{\Delta S}{S} * \Gamma * \Delta S$? (assuming it's an instant move so ignoring $\theta$) I also tried to think from a portfolio perspective if I move underlying up and down, and just take an average on how many deltas has moved, it still lead me to  this formula.
I am having a hard time connecting the two, not sure what I am missing.
Thanks!

confused by the above:
say your delta is delta0 to start. If the mkt moves dS then delta1 = delta0 + gammadS. Now your delta PnL is delta0dS. your Gamma PnL is gamma * dS * dS/2. Why you divide by two is that your delta only grows to delta1 when you get to S+dS. Therefore, on average your delta over that move is delta0 + gamma * dS/2

Basically I'm not sure why you're looking at relative changes.. if you are then you need to rescale your gamma to be per % as opposed to be $. Look at dollar gamma

@user68819 Yes you are right! I didn't rescale my gamma when looking at relative moves... Now they reconcile to each other. Thank you for the help!
